# Calling a batch file using relative path

Tags: batch-file, batch, path

Oh gosh, gotta expose myself as a noob here ;)

In Windows, I need to execute a batch file in a subdirectory of the working directory. However, just running `subdir/foo.bat cmd1 cmd2` does not work, and I get an error saying

> The command "subdir" cannot be found.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different ways to do this.

If dirs are:

c:\workdir\batfile-dir\

and you are currently in \workdir\

You can do this: .\batfile-dir\foo.bat

The thing to remember is that foo.bat will be running with a "current directory" of \workdir\

HTH

Comment: Oh my goodness. I used slashes instead of backslashes. Another reason to hate on Windows, possibly...?

Thanks for your help, anyways. It's appreciated.

Comment: There's no need for the leading ".\"